# Transfer touches to subView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I have a UITableView with Custom Cells, when you touch the cell it adds a subview of a UIImageView.

I want the image to disappear after the user lifts there finger and i have a touchesEnded method on the UIImageVIew Subview but its never called.

It is only called if you lift your finger then press it down again and release it.

How do I get the method to be called on the original touch ended.

Im kinda going for what Snapchat does when you view images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the subview does not get the `touchesEnded` event is that it has not received the `touchesBegan` event: these two come in pairs - whichever view gets the touches began is going to get the touches ended. Your `UIImageView` could not get `touchesEnded` because it wasn't there at the time; it gets `touchesEnded` the second time around when you press down and release because it's there for both events.

There are several ways around this problem:

- **Process view removal in the same place where you process the addition of `UIImageView`** - when you add the subview, store a `__weak` reference to it in a separate variable. When the view that added the `UIImageView` gets the `touchesEnded` event, go to that variable, and remove subview.
- **Keep `UIImageView` there, but control its transparency** - rather than adding and removing the subvuew, start it as fully transparent, then make it opaque on touch, then make it transparent again on release.
- **Don't add the temporary `UIImageView` at all, use `CALayer` instead** - it looks like you are adding the image view simply to host an image in it for a short time. There is a simpler way of doing it that's much lighter-way - using `CALayer`. This approach should be easier to implement, because the layer does not participate in handling of touch events.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the touchBegan method is on the Cell. That's when the subview gets added.

The touch has already been recorded by the Cell. The *Cell's* touchesEnded is what's going to be called when you lift up your finger. So that's where you need to handle removing the subview from the screen. Save a reference to the subview in the cell class, and if it is not equal to `nil`, remove it on touchesEnded. Simple as that.

The touch began *on the Cell*, before the subview existed. That same touch is going to end *on the cell*. You can't transfer the touch to another view while it's in progress.

Comment: I had that at first but i couldn't move my finger around because as soon as the touch leaves the area where the cell is located it stops calling touch methods.

Answer (score 0):

When you touch that view and raise your finger, you should not drag your finger. If you did like that, then touchesCancelled: method will get called. So I think your view is too small to touch. If yes, then make a big View and try it again. It will work for you then.

Comment: make the subview big or the original view that init the subview?

Comment: the subview is the size of the screen.